# There is a conjecture according to which only five Fibonacci numbers are also triangular numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

The numbers are:
$$ f_1 = f_2 = 1 = T_1 $$
$$ f_4 = 3 = T_2 $$
$$ f_8 = 21 = T_6 $$
$$ f_{10} = 55 = T_{10} $$
But how can I prove that these numbers are the only ones? Or is this conjecture wrong and are there more Fibonacci numbers that are also triangular?
Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: The conjecture has been proven to be true, but the first proof of this result would be too long to explain completely here.  See [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A039595) and [the paper proving the result](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/27-2/ming.pdf).

Comment: Make it an answer, maybe?

Comment: Can you prove there are just a finite number of integer points on the curves $5x^2(x+1)^2-4y^2=\pm 16$?

Comment: Thank you for the bibliographic reference JMoravitz.